# Different `on('message')` callback per MQTT topic in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I use MQTT.js. Is it possible to define a different callback per topic?

For example, I subscribe to topics `a`, `b`, and `c` and create an on `message` callback per topic like so:

```js
client.on('message', 'a', cb)
client.on('message', 'b', cb)
client.on('message', 'b', cb)
```

If not, how can I work this around? Any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible.

You just need to add a `if/else` or `switch` block to your on `message` callback that uses the topic as the selector.

e.g.

```
client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
  switch(topic) {
    case 'a':
      ...
      break;
    case 'b':
      ...
      break;
    default:
      ...
  }
})
```

or store callback function in an object and use topics as the key e.g.

```
var callbacks = {}

callbacks["a"] = function(message) {...}

client.on('message', function(topic, message) {

  callbacks[topic](message)

})
```

Comment: I thought so. However, it does not solve my problem (I need to modify the callback runtime), therefore I see just one solution: create a client per topic, which seems to be an overkill for my use case, however, that way I can have a cb per topic.

Comment: No it doesn't, you can store callback function in an object and map them by topic. Edited answer

Comment: Nice idea, however, (another undisclosed information), it won’t solve my problem, as I have a Nest.js app with one `MqttModule` (where I create the client, subscribe to topics, etc) and several other modules that utilise that module. Of course, I can add a method parameter and insert the topic callback into the variable in `MqttModule`. Another issue is I would create 60 instances of each topic callback with a single variable difference: if I follow your suggestion, there would be much code duplication. … Anyway, there is a typo: `callback["a"]` → ``callbacks["a"]`.

Comment: I could use regex though …